# How to avoid rendering space between two `<span>` elements

Tags: html, angularjs

### Concatenate 2 values selected 2 drop down fields, no space

using the 2 strings selected in 2 drop down boxes and combining them into a single string with no spaces in between

I searched for ways to do this with CSS or HTML but cannot figure this out.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To Department</h3>
    <select name="departments" ng-model="departmentSelect" [(value)]="departmentSelected">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='COP-'>OPERATIONS</option>
      <option value='TLG-'>LOGISTICS</option>
      <option value='TR-'>RECRUITING</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To State</h3>
    <select name="states" ng-model="stateSelect" [(value)]="stateSelected">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='AZ'>ARIZONA</option>
      <option value='CA'>CALIFORNIA</option>
      <option value='CO'>COLORADO</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h3 id="departmentSelect">You selected: </h3>
  <span class="selected" ng-bind="departmentSelect">{{departmentSelected}}</span>
  <span class="selected" ng-bind="stateSelect">{{stateSelected}} </span>
</body>
```

a space is added between the two:  COP- AZ
I need it to be COP-AZ

Comment: The banana in a box `[(value)]` is Angular 2+ syntax and is ignored by the AngularJS framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this => ng-bind="(departmentSelect) + (stateSelect)"

```html
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To Department</h3>
    <select name="departments" ng-model="departmentSelect" [(value)]="departmentSelected">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='COP-'>OPERATIONS</option>
      <option value='TLG-'>LOGISTICS</option>
      <option value='TR-'>RECRUITING</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To State</h3>
    <select name="states" ng-model="stateSelect" [(value)]="stateSelected">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='AZ'>ARIZONA</option>
      <option value='CA'>CALIFORNIA</option>
      <option value='CO'>COLORADO</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h3 id="departmentSelect">You selected: </h3>
  
  <span class="selected" ng-bind="(departmentSelect) + (stateSelect) "></span>
  </p>
</body>
```

Comment: The banana in a box `[(value)]` is Angular 2+ syntax and is ignored by the AngularJS framework.

Comment: @georgeawg Yes you are absolutely right it can be removed from the code .i didn't notice that

Comment: Thank you!!  This is what i needed,

Answer (score 0):

Don't put any white space beween the closing tag `</span>` and the opening tag of the second `<span>`:

```
  <span class="selected" ng-bind="departmentSelect"
  ></span><span class="selected" ng-bind="stateSelect"></span>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="">
  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To Department</h3>
    <select name="departments" ng-model="departmentSelect">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='COP-'>OPERATIONS</option>
      <option value='TLG-'>LOGISTICS</option>
      <option value='TR-'>RECRUITING</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div>
    <h3>Ship and Bill To State</h3>
    <select name="states" ng-model="stateSelect">
      <option value="">--Select--</option>
      <option value='AZ'>ARIZONA</option>
      <option value='CA'>CALIFORNIA</option>
      <option value='CO'>COLORADO</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <h3 id="departmentSelect">You selected: </h3>
  <span class="selected" ng-bind="departmentSelect"
  ></span><span class="selected" ng-bind="stateSelect"></span>

</body>
```